# Wildcard url in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

You can define a Google Cloud Function as:

```
exports.functionName = (req, res) => {
  count++;

  // Note: the total function invocation count across
  // all instances may not be equal to this value!
  res.send(`Instance execution count: ${count}`);
};
```

I'm wondering if you can allow a catch-all, such as accept any parameter under:

`https://us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/functionName/*/`

The goal is to host some dynamically generated files over GCF, and currently I can't see an obvious way to allow some sort of wildcard url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `req` object is an Express.js [Request object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req), so you can use it just like the API docs suggest.  [`req.path`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path) will tell you the path of the request including any path parts after the name of the function in the URL.  So, you can parse that and do what you want with the data in there.

Comment: `exports.functionName` the path of the url is `cloudfunctions.com/functionName`. With what you provided, does this mean any sub-path on that same base piece will direct to it?

So `cloudfunctions.com/functionName/dynamicfil123321321123123.js` will go through it?